# How do I simulate Glances and Long Look in Apple Watch simulator?

Tags: ios8, apple-watch

The hardware is not released yet and I want to simulate those events. How do I go about doing that?

Here's the [Apple docs explaining Long Look](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/WatchHumanInterfaceGuidelines/Notifications.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Xcode navigate to `Product -> Scheme -> Manage Schemes`tap on your current WatchApp scheme at duplicate it two times. 
Rename first duplicate to, for example, `WatchApp-Glance` and second to `WatchApp-Notification`.
Choose Glance scheme, choose `Edit` and then in `Info` tab you can select `Watch Interface` to `Glance`. Edit your notification scheme accordingly. You can choose Dynamic and Static version of notification, but let's focus on static for now.
[image]

Then you can `Close` this window.

**Glance**

Open your Storyboard, navigate to Utilities pane, open Object Library and Drag-and-Drop Glance Interface Controller. Choose WatchApp-Glance from your target menu to run on iPhone simulator. Your Glance should now be visible.

**Long-Look Notification**

First off all Long-Look notification divide into Static and Dynamic. If Watch wont't able to render your Dynamic Interface it will switch to Static.
Open your Storyboard, navigate to Utilities pane, open Object Library and Drag-and-Drop Notification Interface Controller. You will see `Static Notification Controller`. In `Attributes Inspector` you can select `Has Dynamic Interface` so you can design your dynamic Long-Look notification interface. However I wasn't able to run it even when I set Dynamic Notification in my scheme. (Xcode-Beta5).

Last thing to set is example json/apns file. In Xcode choose File->New->File (or Cmd+N) from left menu choose AppleWatch and then "Notification Simualtion File".
Then you can run your notification the same way you run Glance.

**Note**

`"category": "myCategory"` in example notification file refers to this:
[image]

So you can build multiple static notifications interfaces in your Storyboard and Watch will decide, during runtime, which should be displayed, based on this string parameter.

Hope this helps.

Comment: any luck with triggering the dynamic notification? been testing it on simulator but it keeps triggering the Static Notification

Comment: Nope - I didn't check that for a while. You sure you have "has dynamic interface" flag enabled?